# Level difference between 2 AKG CK91 capsules

Tags: microphone, preamp

I have recently borrowed two AKG SE300B preamps from a friend each with a AKG CK91 capsule.

The two CK91 capsules seem to have a difference in level of about 6db, which seems quite a lot to me.
I have realized this when I put them on a stereo bar in an A/B-stereo setup (being parallel to each other and facing forward) and pointed them at different sound sources including a speaker.

To investigate further I have wired up one of the SE300B preamps with one capsule, put it in front of a Yamaha HS80M and did a Measurement using a Sine Sweep in Room EQ Wizard. I then exchanged only the capsule and did another measurement.
This is a screenshot of the two measurements:
[image: frequency response]

The frequency response looks quite similar from this zoom level, but the levels are off. (Of course the frequency response is heavily influenced by the speaker, the room, etc.)

**Is it normal for two capsules of the same model to have such level differences?**

**Do I just set the preamp levels different to compensate this?**

Comment: What does the manufacturer say about this?

Comment: @Andyaka I have not contacted them yet. I thought it maybe was something that happens with microphones in general. I haven't found anything about it on the internet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not normal for two capsules of the same model to have such a level difference. A few tenths of dB would be acceptable, unless you have ordered factory paired capsules (which you should do if you intent is to use them in a stereo setup) which should match more closely.

Using the preamp to compensate this will not not give optimum results, especially for a stereo setup, although it can be a temporary workaround.

As the tests you have been doing seem to indicate that this issue come neither from the preamp or the cable from the capsule to the preamp, I would try to get these capsules checked by an appropriate service center if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! It must indeed be a problem of the capsules themselves. Yet it still irritates me how the frequency response is so similar while the levels are off.